# Inform programmer with a message when about to use a Usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

First of all I am working with **Visual Studio 2017**. I have create a `UserControl` which requires a **borderless** form. Is there any way to popup a **message** if programmer try to place this control into a **non-borderless form**? Something like the message box which appears in **design view** when we give a **wrong value** at **Properties Window** of any control.

**EDIT**

I noticed that if I add a simple `MsgBox` into my `UserControl`'s `Public Sub New` and then add this `UserControl` to a `Form`, message box appears.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    MsgBox("Test Message")
End Sub
```

But, how can I check if parent form is borderless or not? Something like this example below, which of course doesn't work inside `Public Sub New` because there is no parent yet!!!

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    if Not MyBase.ParentForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None Then
        MsgBox("Test Message")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try overriding the `OnParentChanged` method, which raises the `ParentChanged` event whenever the control is added to another control.

Comment: I should also add that `OnParentChanged` will execute when a control is removed from another control, so be sure to check that `Parent` isn't `Nothing` first.

Comment: Can I have an example please?

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples you found when you searched the web? If I post a comment it's to provide keywords for you to search for yourself. Otherwise I'd have posted an answer. If someone provides you with information, make an attempt to use it first, then ask for more information if and when you need it. Don't just wait for it all to be handed to you.

Comment: My friend Jim, if you take a look at my questions you will see that I never wait to be handed to me anything. I am asking for an example only because I can't understand how to use your informations, even after I looked for it on the web. I am not any VB.NET specialist and I am still trying to learn things. If the best you can do is to give some keywords, it's acceptable, really thank you for your time, but I don't believe you have the right to offend any person which you don't really know.

Comment: I told you to override a method. There's plenty of information on the web on overriding methods. There are plenty of EXAMPLES of overriding methods. You don't need to be a VB specialist to search the web.  If you don't understand those examples, what reason is there to believe that you'll understand mine?  I expect to see what you've tried and an explanation of the issue, just as for the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some tests I managed to solved it...

Into `UserControl`'s `Load` event (*where `ParentForm` is acceptable*), I check first if `UserControl` is in `DesignMode` (*else user will gets messages everytime application starts*) and then, if `ParentForm` is not `FormBorderStyle.None`, user informed by a `MessageBox`.

```
Private Sub UserControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not Site Is Nothing AndAlso Site.DesignMode Then
        If Not ParentForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None Then
            MessageBox.Show("This control works better with a borderless form!!!", "Control Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```